# TokenException: Unable to add window?

Tags: android, progressdialog

```
private void runDialog(final int seconds){
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
          public void run(){
            try {
                    Thread.sleep(seconds * 1000);
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
              public void run()
              {
                        // Your Alert Code
                        AlertDialog connection = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                NewsScreenActivity.this)
                                .setTitle("No Network Found")
                                .setMessage(
                                        "service unavailable, please try again later")
                                .setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                    int whichButton) {

                                              finish();
                                        //        progressDialog.dismiss();
                                            }
                                        }).create();

                        connection.show();
              }
            });

          }catch (InterruptedException e) {
              Log.i("=================== Connection TimeO5555555555", "======");
             // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "service unavailable, please try again later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
          }
        }).start();
  }
```

error

```
    10-10 17:55:13.299: E/AndroidRuntime(11643): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    10-10 17:55:13.299: E/AndroidRuntime(11643): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@40531320 is not valid; is your activity running?
    10-10 17:55:13.299: E/AndroidRuntime(11643):    at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:528)
    10-10 17:55:13.299: E/AndroidRuntime(11643):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
    10-10 17:55:13.299: E/AndroidRuntime(11643):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
    10-10 17:55:13.299: E/AndroidRuntime(11643):    at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
    10-10 17:55:13.299: E/AndroidRuntime(11643):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
    10-10 17:55:13.299: E/AndroidRuntime(11643):    at com.MariTimeGlobalNews.NewsScreenActivity$7$1.run(NewsScreenActivity.java:587)
    10-10 17:55:13.299: E/AndroidRuntime(11643):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    10-10 17:55:13.299: E/AndroidRuntime(11643):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    10-10 17:55:13.299: E/AndroidRuntime(11643):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    10-10 17:55:13.299: E/AndroidRuntime(11643):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3729)
    10-10 17:55:13.299: E/AndroidRuntime(11643):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    10-10 17:55:13.299: E/AndroidRuntime(11643):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    10-10 17:55:13.299: E/AndroidRuntime(11643):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:874)
    10-10 17:55:13.299: E/AndroidRuntime(11643):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:632)
    10-10 17:55:13.299: E/AndroidRuntime(11643):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: try NewsScreenActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()... instead of runOnUiThread(new Runnable()..

Comment: thanks @imran khan but same error ...

Answer (score 0):

You are holding on to a reference to a Context (either explicitly, or by creating a Dialog or Toast or some other dependent item) that has been destroyed (typically because you are using the onCreateDialog or you passed the Activity to some other process that didn't get destroyed when the Activity was destroyed)

Answer (score 0):

Context Problem in thread.
So please use Handler for it.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html